# Angular JS and jqLite match node to selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jqlite

I'm trying to add a few functions from jQuery into jqLite so that I don't have to load the whole jQuery library with my angular apps. I'm using the technique used by Ben Nadel in this article.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2753-creating-jqlite-plugins-in-angularjs.htm

I am running into difficulty implementing a closestChild plugin like this one.

https://github.com/lolmaus/jquery.closestchild/blob/master/jquery.closestchild.js

Obviously I've rewritten is slightly so it looks like this.

```
JQLite.prototype.closestChild = function(selector) {

            var $children, $results;

            $children = this.children();

            if ($children.length === 0){
                return $();
            }

            $results = $children.filter(selector);

            if ($results.length > 0){
                return $results;
            }
            else{
                return $children.closestChild(selector);
            }

        };
```

...but it leads to this error.

```
Error: [jqLite:nosel] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/jqLite/nosel
```

So, I did a search for the error and found that jqLite isn't able to match with selectors for some reason, only tag names (is this ever useful?). What I can't understand is that it's running alongside Ben's .filter() function from that article which seems to work fine when you give it a selector. That's the exact same function I'm calling in this line.

```
$results = $children.filter(selector);
```

So, I guess my question is, is there a way I can loop through $children and see if any of them match the selector which is passed in using plain javascript, or some other workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you expecting from 'selector', but selector (as it follows from Ben Nadel's code) is either a callback or DOM node.

So it would be would be

```
angular.element(document.body)
.find('div')
.closestChild(function(el) {
    var element = angular.element(el);
    console.log(element);
    return !!element.text();
});
```

jqLite's support of selectors is exactly the same as the manual states: it does only `getElementsByTagName` and only on `find`.

For 'heavier' jqLite implementations you can check [this](https://github.com/quantumui/angular-nojq) and [that](https://github.com/PabloDeGrote/angular-sizzle-standalone) project (they are quite new, I haven't tried them in work yet, so feel free to share your impressions).

Comment: That's brilliant estus, saves me swimming around out of my depth trying to rewrite jqLite. I am tempted to go with the second one because it's the smallest but something is telling me that for a few extra Kb having access to a few extra things like .closest() might be really handy and it's still a lot smaller than jQuery. Thanks again.

Comment: Hope they are good enough. I was about to to power-up jqLite with Sizzle not so long ago until I discovered these ones.